# Вопрос по lifecycle в приложении

Tags: java, android, activity-life-cycle

Если я закрываю приложение, то вызывается какой метод вызывается тогда? `onStop()` или `onDestroy()`? И после того как запускаю приложение снова вызывается метод `onResume()`? Или я немного путаюсь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ради интереса можете после каждого Вашего метода из жизненного цикла добавить что то подобное:

```
Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()")
```

Где  TAG это `final String TAG = "State";` и просто в зависимости от метода, меняйте строковый параметр в ваших логах. Тогда уже при запуске приложения в эммуляторе, вы сможете отследить в Android Monitor'e по строковому ресурсу State вы сможете отследить Ваши состояния. Вот небольшой [пример](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/60-urok-23-activity-lifecycle-v-kakih-sostojanijah-mozhet-byt-activity.html).

Answer (score 2):

По жизненным циклам `Activity` и `Fragment` в своё время очень помогла [эта схемка](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xxv/android-lifecycle/master/complete_android_fragment_lifecycle.png).